# When I populate a jTable from a CachedRowSet using the DefaultTableModel, why is the JTable's column title not updated?

Tags: java, rmi

When I populate a jTable from a CachedRowSet using the DefaultTableModel, the jtable column's title wasn't updated. So I did it manually using the jtable property. Is there any alternative way to get the title name automatically from the database?

**This the client**

```
 public studentdetails() 
 {
        initComponents();
    
    try {           
                       
         Interface b = (Interface) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/Server");
              DefaultTableModel tblModel = 
              (DefaultTableModel)studentdetailstable.getModel();
              tblModel.setRowCount(0);
              CachedRowSet studentdetails=b.getArray();
                     
              while(studentdetails.next())
              {   
                   Vector t = new Vector();
                           
                   for(int i = 0; i <= studentdetails.getMaxRows(); i++) 
                   {
                     t.add(studentdetails.getInt("id"));
                     t.add(studentdetails.getString("names"));
                   }       
                     tblModel.addRow(t);
        }
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        } 
    }
```

**Implementation**

```
public CachedRowSet getArray() throws RemoteException {
        try (Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
             Statement st = con.createStatement();
             //  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from studentnames")) 
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select id, names from students"))                               {
             RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
             CachedRowSet details= factory.createCachedRowSet();
             fruitDetails.populate(rs);
             return details;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RemoteException("Method 'getArray()' failed.", e);
        }
```

Comment: I fixed that sir. I had done small mistake. Unfortunately, I didn't notice that. Is there any way to update the jtable column title automatically from the database?

Comment: Sir, I didn't get it properly. Can you be able to upload the code?  Then, I can be able to understand. Else, it's okay sir. I will manage with manual naming. I feel it is not a big issue. But, It will be nice if I get how to do automatically.

Comment: Because there is no code here that updates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CachedRowSet` inherits method `getMetaData` which returns [ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) which can be used to get the names of the columns as well as the column count. (See below code. More explanation after the code.)

```java
/* Required imports.

import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
*/
public studentdetails() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        Interface b = (Interface) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/Server");
        CachedRowSet details = b.getArray();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = details.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<>(columnCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            columnNames.add(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i + 1));
        }
        Vector<Object> rows = new Vector<>();
        while (details.next()) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<>(columnCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                row.add(details.getObject(i + 1));
            }
            rows.add(row);
        }
        DefaultTableModel tblModel = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames);
        studentdetailstable.setModel(tblModel);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`DefaultTableModel` contains a `Vector` whose elements are `Vector`s. Each element is a row in the `JTable`. Hence, in the above code, I create and populate a `Vector` that can serve as one of the parameters to the `DefaultTableModel` constructor. The other parameter to the `DefaultTableModel` constructor is a `Vector` containing the names of the columns in the `JTable`. As I already said, the column names can be obtained from the `ResultsetMetaData`.

After creating a new `DefaultTableModel`, I simply assign it to the `JTable` via method `setModel`.